# Terminal Server Windows Server 2003 Desktop Shortcuts

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I have locked down my Terminal Server using GPO and putting the computer in the GPO, the problem I have is I am trying to add shortcuts to applications to the users desktop using logon scripts and they don't appear unless the user uses windows explorer and then they are given a warning about how it has been restriced by administrator but when they click on desktop within it they appear?

This is the document I followed to lockdown the server:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=12117

Is there an easy way to make the shortcuts appear on the actual desktop for each user and remove the restricted by administrator user message?

Comment: Don't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke Shell32.SHChangeNotify to inform it that the desktop shortcuts have changed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986869/force-the-icons-on-the-desktop-to-refresh-after-deleting-items-or-stop-an-item

http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/8322.aspx

SHChangeNotify function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx